# I'm not getting the response from a webpage

Tags: java, android, web, bufferedreader

I'm very new to Java/Android and I have a code to get the response of a webpage. I have a code like this, but for some reason the `BufferedReader`'s `in.readLine()` is always returning null.

```
URL url = new URL(endPoint);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout);
connection.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(encodedParams.getBytes().length));
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

// Setup the POST payload
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(encodedParams);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

// Read the response
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
```

Not sure where I'm making the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have proxy setting in your place??? if "yes" url connection won't work..

Answer (score 0):

try

```
connection.connect();
```

before reading the response

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. I added connect() method and I'm getting no response as again. No exception been thrown too.